# problem with layer of preload - website

Tags: javascript, html, css, preload

In this website [www.wirecreation.net](http://www.wirecreation.net) sometimes I have a problem with the initial load. I don't know why, the gray div with the logo and the progress bar sometimes has a margin with some pixels, but sometimes not and the margin is zero. I think the problem only exists in chrome...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

it is solved with

```
width:100% !important;
height:100% !important;
```

thanks